# error 404 Vue cli

Tags: vuejs

Subi una aplicación a un host con VueJs Cli y funciona bién, excepto cuando hago el **F5** me dice: 
*

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an  ErrorDocument to handle the request.

*

Pues cuando lo desarrollo localmente todo esta bién, pero el error es al subirlo y pues varios usuarios podrían hacer F5 y saldria ese error...

Comment: Hola 7binary, para poder brindarle ayuda, nos podría proporcionar "algo" del proyecto en donde cree que se encuentra el error?.

Comment: qué webserver tienes arriba? es apache o nginx?